# Formerly Working Code that Calls google.script.run. Failing

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Something changed this afternoon that broke all of my Google App Scripts that are deployed as web apps. At the moment every call to:

google.script.run.[anything]

from the interface (HTML side) to backend fails.  If you go to something like Chrome's console it says the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

Firefox's developer tools are a little more explicit:

TypeError: google.script is undefined

So somehow google.script is no longer defined.  Is this a bug Google introduced?  Do we now need to call a script to get these methods (in the way we need to call https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad for other features)?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean "formerly" not "formally" right?

Comment: I'm actually getting the same issue since a few hours, maybe it's a temporary issue. EDIT: it has been submitted as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37544412

Comment: It's working from my sidebars and dialogs.  I don't have any web apps.

Comment: Mine works just fine. Perhaps it was just fixed? Or maybe it's an update pushed just to some users. My account is a G Suite account so we get slightly different updates I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [see workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284867/512127). You need to load the Google File Picker using the Google API Loader library.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! I wish I understood why it worked, however.  Is there a race condition when we call on the onload get parameter?  I'm not understanding why the load method for the File Picker would impact the google.script methods.

Comment: @tazz_ben Erik from the Google Apps Script team says " the cause of the problem is that when the Picker API loads into google.picker, it is currently overwriting google.script, so google.script.run() calls start failing." https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127474#comment36